# need sql, a tricky one

Tags: sql

suppose I have three relations

> part(partno,partname,color) partno is P.K
>   supplier(supplierno,sname) supplierno is P.K
>   part_supplier(supplierno,partno) supplierno, partno is P.K.

Now i want to get the name of the suppliers who supply parts of only one color.

Comment: Looks like homework?

Comment: Why is that important?

Comment: @DanBracuk: As a student you should at least try to do homework on your own. If you still can't solve a problem then you might ask. Of course you should also what you've tried so far.

Comment: Does that not also apply to people who are attempting to do this stuff for a living?

Comment: If you need help for this type of question you're not doing SQL for a living :-) This question looks directly copied from a Chris Date  textbook: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppliers_and_Parts_database

Comment: Sorry to everyone.actually mistakenly i have added this question my question was i want to know the name of the suppliers who supply parts of same color. if i do select a.pno,b.color from part a,part b  where a.color=b.color and a.pno<>b.pno then i can get the parts of same color. then i stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.supplierno
FROM supplier AS s
JOIN part_supplier AS ps
  ON s.supplierno = ps.supplierno
JOIN part AS p
  ON ps.partno = p.partno
GROUP BY s.supplierno
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.color) = 1 -- only one color for all parts
```

Answer (score 1):

The having clause is your freind.

```
select field1, etc, count(*) records
from yourTables
where whatever
group by field1, etc
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: This returns unique rows, but this is not what the OP asked for :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sup.sname,count(*) from part_supplier Map
inner join supplier sup
on map.supplierno=sup.supplierno
inner join part par
on Map.partno=par.partno
group by sup.sname 
having count(*)=1
```

Comment: This returns suppliers how supply only one part, but this is not what the OP asked for :-)

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT S.sname 
FROM part P, supplier S, part_supplier PS
WHERE S.supplierno = ps.supplierno AND
      PS.partno = P.partno
GROUP BY P.partno
HAVING count(P.color) = 1
```

Tables :

```
CREATE TABLE supplier (
  supplierno     INT          PRIMARY KEY,
  suppliername   VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE part (
  partno     INT          PRIMARY KEY,
  partname   VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL,
  color   INT          NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE part_supplier (
  supplierno INT          NOT NULL REFERENCES supplier(supplierno),
  partno     INT          NOT NULL REFERENCES part(partno),
  PRIMARY KEY (supplierno, partno)
);
```

Some data for testing :

```
INSERT INTO part VALUES (1, 'a',1), (2, 'b',2), (3, 'c',3), 
                        (4, 'd',1), (5, 'e',2), (6, 'c',3), 
                        (7, 'd',1), (8, 'e',2), (9, 'e',3);

INSERT INTO supplier VALUES (1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3,'c');

INSERT INTO part_supplier VALUES (1,1), (2,1), (3,3), 
                                 (4,1), (5,1), (6,1), 
                                 (7,2), (8,2), (9,3);
```